# ODOO 12.0 MIGRATION: External ID not found in the system: stock_account

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

**Trying to migrate a module from odoo 10 to odoo 12 but it shows me this error,it seems that stock_account doesn't exist.**

```
raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
    odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: stock_account.view_picking_inherit_form2" while parsing /home/*/PycharmProjects/Odoo12/*/invoice_in_picking/views/stock_view.xml:37, near
    <record id="view_picking_inherit_form3" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">stock.picking.form.inherit3</field>
                <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock_account.view_picking_inherit_form2"/>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <field name="move_lines" position="attributes">
                        <attribute name="context">{'default_invoice_state': invoice_state, 'address_in_id': partner_id, 'form_view_ref':'stock.view_move_picking_form', 'tree_view_ref':'stock.view_move_picking_tree', 'default_picking_type_id': picking_type_id, 'default_location_id': location_id, 'default_location_dest_id': location_dest_id}</attribute>
                    </field>
                </field>
            </record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting says that the External ID does not exist. You're getting this error because, while the `stock_account` module still exists in Odoo 12, the view (`view_picking_inherit_form2`) does not exist.

You need to determine which Odoo 12 view you want to inherit from - most likely `stock.view_picking_form`.

However, you also need to look at the contents of that form because a lot has changed since Odoo 10. For example, the field you are trying to change `attributes` on (`move_lines`) does not exist either; it is replaced by `move_ids_without_package`.

---

Inheriting views is more or less the same in 12, but before you migrate any of your view contents to Odoo 12, you need to ask yourself a few questions.

1. Do I even need to do this in 12?
2. Does the module I inherit from exist in 12?
3. Does the view I inherit from exist in 12?
4. Are the view contents the same in 12?

Here's a link to [the Views Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/views.html)

Comment: Thank you a lot, your answer was very helpfull